# No se envian los datos de XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Tengo un XMLHttpRequest con el que quiero enviar un string, pero este recibe array(0) en el alert, antes con x-www-form-urlencoded y sin el stringify funcionaba pero no recibia los datos en el post, pero ahora ni siquiera eso, pero he leido que es como deberia hacerse para enviar un string, a continuacion os dejo el JS y el .php para que podais verlo, muchas gracias de antemano :)
JS:

```
        var img = chartR.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById('base64').value = img;
        var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert(xhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", base_url_admin+"record/reporte", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": img});
        xhttp.send(data);
```

PHP:

```
$resultChartImg = $_POST;
var_dump($resultChartImg);exit();
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @A.Cedano {"resultChartImg":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgB......"}

Comment: ¿El valor es **exactamente** esto: `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgB......"` o los `....` significa que habría más cosas? Es importante que sea un JSON válido. Prueba con algo como: `let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": "test"});` pues sospecho que en `img` habría algo que crea un objeto no válido.

Comment: @A.Cedano sigue siendo array(0), los ... es porque el string es muy largo

Comment: Prueba a mandar esto: `let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": "test"});`  así sabremos si es un problema de `img`. ¿No tienes forma de ver el valor completo de `img`?

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he probado y sigue siendo array(0), y si lo puedo ver completo, pero no cabe en la respuesta de stack overflow porque es muy largo, de todas formas son todo caracteres y numeros, no tiene nada mas

Comment: Si al pasar esto: `let data = JSON.stringify({"resultChartImg": "test"});` te da `array(0)` entonces es el POST el que no funciona. Verifica que la URL es correcta, me refiero a `base_url_admin+"record/reporte"` y prueba a poner también un `var_dump($_REQUEST);` en el código PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que antes en vez de application/json tenia application/x-www-form-urlencoded y funcionaba menos el responseText, asique interpreto que esta bien

Comment: @A.Cedano era por el exit(); del php, pero ahora el $_REQUEST muestra array(0). La URL esta bien y ahora me muestra la imagen codificada en el console.log cuando hago console.log(data), como la llamo desde el reporte.php?

Comment: El `exit();` no impide nada ahí, de hecho, debe ponerse para que no haya más salida por pantalla. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` se pone cuando quieres mandar los datos en la URL (en ese caso sería una petición GET) ... Nada de eso es el problema, pero tampoco entiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, ¿podrías explicar lo que quieres hacer con la imagen que envías al servidor?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137151/discussion-between-daniel-morales-and-a-cedano).